# Pandas, Como resaltar valor de DF según criterios

Tags: python, pandas

necesito resaltar valores de un DF según ciertos criterios, por ejemplo en la columna "NSEI" para cada celda resaltar los "BL_SY" , "WO_EX" y obtener algo similar al print:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente hacerlo con

> df.style.applymap()

pero no me funciona... o bien poder resaltar la celda entera cuando la misma contenga almenos 1 "BL_SY"

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a crear un dataframe de ejemplo para mostrar el resultado (ya que no has proporcionado en la pregunta datos de ejemplo, sino como imagen, inventaré los míos propios por no ponerme a copiar lo que sale en la imagen).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "BTS": [112, 5, 14, 10],
    "Operativo": ["WO", "WO", "WO", "WO"],
    "NSEI":  ["dkajshdkjsajdlslks", "sh BL_SY ss", "sajdklasjdoajsdlk", "BL_SYSdaslkdjslk"]
})
```

Puedes usar la función `df.style.applymap()` como tú mismo sugieres. A esa función hay que pasarle como primer parámetro otra función, la cual será invocada para cada celda. Esta otra función, según el contenido de la celda, debe retornar una cadena que será usada como estilo CSS para esa celda.

Así pues voy a programar una función que mire si dentro de la celda aparece un cierto texto y en ese caso retorne un background rojizo (o blanco si el texto no está):

```
def resalta_texto(contenido, a_buscar):
  return 'background-color: {}'.format(
      "#ffaaaa" if a_buscar in contenido else "white")
```

Esto coloreará la celda completa (por desgracia no hay forma de colorear sólo parte del texto).

Para aplicarlo sólo a una columna se le pasa el parámetro adicional `subset`. Así:

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: resalta_texto(x, "BL_SY"), subset=["NSEI"])
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: excelente @abulafia  era lo que estaba buscado... gracias por tu tiempo  saludos...